# What is actually going on with atoi in this situation?

Tags: c++, c, atoi

I'm relatively new to C and I'm curious why I'm having problems with `atoi` in this situation. I feel like I am not understanding something fundamental. Here is my sample code:

```
int main()
{
    char last[3];
    last[2]='\0';
    uint16_t num1;
    uint16_t num2;

    // I read in num1 and num2 from a file and do an integer operation on them. bigarray is the file contents. bigarray[i] is a integer
    num1=bigarray[i] - 1;
    num2=bigarray[i+1] - 1;
    last[0]=(char)num1;
    last[1]=(char)num2;
    printf("%i\n:", atoi(last));
}
```

When I print out  `last[0]` and `last[1]` seperatly it gives me the correct values. When I print out `atoi(last)` then it gives me `0`.

Why does `atoi` give me `0` in this situation, and how can I fix it?

Comment: -1 underspecified question (e.g., it's about incorrect values but fails to specify the values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`atoi` expects ASCII characters, so if the array is, let's say `last[0] = 1` and `last[1] = 2`, it will find no characters, if it was  `last[0] = '1'` and `last[1] = '2'` than it would print `12`.

In this particular case you can achieve that by:

```
last[0]='0' + num1;
last[1]='0' + num2;
```

(assuming `num1` and `num2` are between 0-9)

Short edit to explain the idea:

The ascii values of the digits `'0'`(0x30) to `'9'`(0x39) are sequential, so adding `0` to `'0'` (0x30) will give you `'0'`(0x30) and adding `2` to `'0'`(0x30) will give you `'2'`(0x32)

Comment: Indeed. The characters represented by 1 and 2 are control characters.

Comment: @Rell3oT, the integer value of `'0'` is 48. The ASCII numbers are in the range 48-57. So `'0' + 5 == 48 + 5 == 53` which is the ASCII number for `'5'`. Another nice way of looking at it is hex: any number is `0x3_`, where the `_` is the number you want.

Comment: Thats hilarious...because In my actual code I was subtracting 48 (not 1)...I guess I was trying to do the job of atoi.  Thanks!

Comment: The cast to `char` is useless. `'0'` has type `int`, and even if it didn't, the addition operator would promote both operands back to `int` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are trying to print out the array. Do you want to print out a single value? Or all the values using a for loop?

Comment: What's being printed is the int returned from `atoi`, which should be 0 due to a bad number format.

Answer (score 0):

This `last[0]=(char)num1;` just casts the number to a character but its value is maintained (and truncated in your situation, since `num1` is 16 bits long).

So you are not converting a number to its `char*` representation before using `atoi`, you are just casting numbers on different types (no ASCII encoding is involved).

Answer (score 0):

`atoi()` works on null-terminated ascii strings, not numbers.
You probably just want `printf("%d%d\n", num1, num2);`

assigning a number to a char is not the same as making that string a readable representation of that number as ASCII decimal digits. For that, try `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
char a=48;
printf("%i",a); //this would give you an output of 48
printf("%c",a); //this would give you an output of 0
printf("%c",48); //this would give you an output of 48
printf("%i",atoi(a)); //this would give you an output of 0
printf("%i",atoi("50")); //this would give you an output of 2
```

The atoi() function, requires the values to be on the ascii format.
Meaning character '0' is equal to integer 48.
Meaning character '1' is equal to integer 49.
Meaning character '2' is equal to integer 50.
...and so on and so forth

when you do typecasting, you're only changing the data size. such as from your codes

```
...
last[0]=(char)num1;
...
```

the size of the data coming from num1 is trimmed down so that it could be fitted into a character datatype, before storing it to the character type variable, but the value is still the same as stored in num1.

so, if you're planning to still do that, just change these lines

```
...
last[0]=(char)num1;
last[1]=(char)num1;
...
```

to

```
...
last[0]=(char)num1+48;
last[1]=(char)num2+48;
...
```

or even this would do

```
...
last[0]=num1+48;
last[1]=num2+48;
...
```

And after changing the lines of codes above, you can correctly display the values using the code

```
...
printf("%i\n:", atoi(last));
...
```